# How to skip tracing of http OPTIONS requests

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

Is it possible to configure sleuth to ignore http OPTIONS requests? In my case it's CORS preflight requests made by the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter spans using a [`SpanHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-zipkin-custom-reported-spans) or prevent sampling them using a [`SamplerFunction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-sampling)

Comment: I think what you're suggesting is preventing certain spans from being sent to external systems (e.g. Zipkin), similar to the `spring.sleuth.span-filter.span-name-patterns-to-skip` property. What I need is to prevent sleuth from tracing http OPTIONS requests, something similar to the `spring.sleuth.web.skip-pattern` but for http methods instead.

Comment: I added [`SamplerFunction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-sampling) to my answer, that's what `spring.sleuth.web.skip-pattern` uses too.

Comment: Thank you, `SamplerFunction` is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Nick can you provide solution for this problem? I have the same situation.

Comment: I managed it by adding this bean:
`@Bean
SamplerFunction<org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.http.HttpRequest> sleuthHttpServerSampler() {
   return httpRequest -> !httpRequest.method().equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.toString());
}`